# How to find the distribution of the entries in this matrix?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, expected-value, matrix

Given that the entries of the matrix $\mathbf{Z}$ are i.i.d complex normal distributed with mean zero and variance $\sigma^{2}$, will the entries of the matrix $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Z}^{H} \mathbf{Z}$ be i.i.d Gaussian too? What can be said about their mean and variance? (I am tasked with finding the variance of the entries).

Comment: Consider the case of a $1\times 1$ matrix: can you solve that version?